# How to display multiple selected photos using image_picker?

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

Added image_picker to the application. How can I make it display multiple selected photos in body? My code is not working.
My code:

```js
  final List<XFile>? selectedImagesList = [];
  final _picker = ImagePicker();

  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
    if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        selectedImagesList!.addAll(selectedImages);
      });
    }
  }]
```

Body:

```js
Center(
                child: selectedImagesList != null
                    ? Wrap(
                        children: selectedImagesList!.map((imageone) {
                          return Container(
                              child: Card(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: Image.file(File(imageone.path)),
                            ),
                          ));
                        }).toList(),
                      )
                    : Container()),
```

Comment: What is your error ? Cause' i copy your code and it works

Comment: It works? In my simulator, when I select pictures and click Add, nothing happens.

Comment: What version of image_picker do you have ?

Comment: 0.8.5 and use ios simulator

Comment: I think the error comes from the ios simulator, read this and try to test it in a real device : https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#ios